# Reference to a queue that resides on function stack

Tags: c++, queue

Here is some C++ code that use a queue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

void print(queue<int>& q){
    int n = q.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int front = q.front();
        cout<<front<<" ";
        q.pop();
        q.push(front);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(queue<T>& q){
    queue<T> q2;
    for(int i=4;i<7;i++)
        q2.push(i);
    q = q2;
}

int main(){

    queue<int>q;
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
        q.push(i);
    print(q);

    foo(q);
    print(q);

}
```

A queue `q` is declared in the `main` function and is passed as a reference in the function `foo`. But it is reassigned to another queue `q2` that occupies memory inside the function stack space.

From what I understand, after the function `foo` terminates, the reference variable should point to an invalid memory address as the queue `q2` would have been destroyed.

Could anyone help me with these two questions? 
1. Why does `q` hold the correct elements of `q2`, even though the queue `q2` has been destroyed after function call terminates. 
2. A reference variable is supposed to a initialized only once. But it seems we can assign it different values as many times as we like. Why is this allowed?

I have been thinking of this being an implication of deep copy. But I have not been able to find the internal implementation of the copy assignment operator that queue STL has. I would be great if someone could help me with a link to that.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. Where you went wrong is this part "q.. is reassigned to another queue q2". This description is inaccurate. What happens there is that `q` is assigned from `q2`; that is the contents of `q2` are placed into `q`. Now go back to this part, and work the rest of it out, and everything will make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding that a reference can only be assigned once is correct. References are *aliases* to objects in the sense that they are not objects themselves, but always *refer* to another object. By design, their syntactic usage is to act as a drop-in replacement for concrete objects in most cases. Pointers on the other hand can be made to point to a different object or to `nullptr`.

The result of `q = q2` is that `q2`'s contents are assigned to the queue *referred to* by `q`. This is indeed a deep copy, and the function-local `q2` is not referred to thereafter, and there is no dangling reference.

Documentation for `queue`'s `operator=` can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/operator%3D).